# Request.Form empty post data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, request.form

Trying to use Request.Form to get the posted payload, but Request.Form it is always {} empty?

Here is my Payload:

[image: chromepayload]

But when I try and use:

```
var responseBytes = Request.HttpMethod == "POST" ? client.UploadValues(url, Request.Form) : client.DownloadData(url);
```

My payload Request.Form is null.

The entire C# code:

```
public ActionResult Index(string pathInfo)
{
    var url = Settings.GetValue<string>("QualService") + "/" + pathInfo + "?" + Request.QueryString;

    //Get stuff from the back end
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Cookie] = Request.Headers["Cookie"];
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " +
                                                          Convert.ToBase64String(
                                                              Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                                                                  "x:{0}".Fmt(UserSession.ApiKey)));
        try
        {
            var responseBytes = Request.HttpMethod == "POST" ? client.UploadValues(url, Request.Form) : client.DownloadData(url);

            var result = new ContentResult();
            result.Content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
            result.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            result.ContentType = "application/json";
            return result;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Logger.Error("Error while proxying to the API:  ", e);
        }
    }

    return Json(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would keep things simple. Change the signature of the action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string pathInfo, string Id, string Name, int ProjectId)
{
    // ID, Name and ProjectId will be populated with the values in the payload.
    // ... Rest of code.

}
```

Specifying `[HttpPost]` will help you here, since the MVC model binder (the class responsible for getting data from, for example, Request.Form) will populate the parameter values by matching their names to data in Request.Form.

Note, I don't know if `Id` is a number or string value. If it's a number then you need

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string pathInfo, int? Id, string Name, int ProjectId)
{
```

In this case, Id is a nullable integer.

Comment: I think I found the problem. Application/json is the post.

Comment: How are you making the POST request, via $.ajax()? You may need to change the `contentType` value to suite your needs.

Comment: $http angular it automatically gives you contentType application/json

Comment: Can you post the code of the Angular $http code please?